# Book Identification: Something to do with "chaos"

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the book long ago in my native language (romanian) and i have a distinct feeling that it had something about "chaos" in the tile (chaos theory or related) yet it might not be part of the original title as it was a translation.

Key points as i remember them:

- the solar system was colonized and ruled by an authoritarian central government
- a "rebel" movement of sorts existed that opposed the central government (they were portrayed as terrorists) and had a hidden secret base
- the hero was some sort of an agent that ended up investigating the 'rebels" and discovering their location and leadership
- there is at some point a discussion between the hero and the "rebel" leader about all absolute power structures being decadent and regressive and about the need of an extremity to oppose the authoritarian center. This was part of a larger balancing act where the extremity eventually becomes the controlling center creating the need for another opposition to be formed and perpetuate the cycle

Comment: You have described the book in abstract and general terms. It might be helpful if you could also provide any concrete details that you can recall. A character name? The kinds of weapons, spaceships, other technology used? Is the rebels secret base on Earth, another planet, a moon, an asteroid? Where is the capital of the central government? Is the head of government called President, Emperor, Empress, King, Queen, Big Brother, Big Sister, Council of Scientists? How long ago did you read it? 10 years? 50 years?

Comment: unfortunately that's all i have :(. i read it during the 90s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your book sounds like Agent of Chaos by Norman Spinrad. The leader of the Hegemonic Council rules the galaxy with tyranny. He is opposed by the agents of Chaos. There is a third group; the Brotherhood of Assassins, who seem to work against both groups. The idea of the book is that chaos is the natural state of the universe and that political order is against the good of mankind.[image]

Comment: This is the book for sure. I remember the title now and the plot better (it was "Agentul haosului" in my native romanian). Time to look it up and buy it for another reading (in original english now)